# How does qiskit metal calculate T1 time

Tags: qiskit, decoherence

We are a group of students working on a project about superconducting qubits. We have used Qiskit Metal to do some simulation and got sets of results of Ec, Ej and coherence time T1. However, we are wondering how Qiskit calculated T1 time. Are there certain equations or math models that the programs use to get the T1 time?
https://qiskit.org/documentation/metal/tut/4-Analysis/4.11-Analyze-and-tune-a-transmon.html
Above is the link to the tutorial that we referenced. We changed the pad width and pad height of the transmon qubit and then used the LOM method to do the analysis.
Thank you in advance!